# Simple way to build a noarch conda package?

Tags: python, conda

I want to build a conda package of a simple pure Python library and host it on [anaconda.org](http://anaconda.org).  I want to do this in roughly one line.

For PyPI/pip I could naively do the following:

```
$ python setup.py register sdist upload
```

Is there an equivalent for [anaconda.org](http://anaconda.org)/conda?  It is important that I be able to support all architectures and a set of Python versions, possibly using a `noarch` package or `conda convert`.  Extra points if it can rely just on my `setup.py` file and no new configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a script, I use this on Windows (powershell):

https://gist.github.com/faph/53e5b76a35f08e9ca974

I did create a conda-recipe first, though. As you can see, I convert platform specific packages. Doesn't work when there are entry points, unfortunately.

Comment: Cool.  If you were to make this in a way that was platform independent (perhaps using Python itself) and publish it on PyPI I'll bet it'd see a lot of use.

Answer (score 1):

conda-build has undocumented (yet) option `build/noarch_python`, added in [PR #317](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/pull/317). It is mentioned [in anaconda-server docs](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-server/easy-gui/features/noarch-packages). A package created with this option is meant to support all architectures and [all Python versions](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/542#issuecomment-130870047).
It also has a few other limitations, for example currently such a package can't be created on Windows.